# Вставить в input файл, выбранный в другом input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Есть 2 input'а:

```
<input type="file" id="first-input>"
<input type="file" id="second-input>"
```

При выборе файла в first-input, он должен вставляться в second-input. Каким образом это можно сделать?
Т.е.:

```
$('#first-input').change(function(){
  var file = $(this)[0].files[0];
  //Как его вставить?
});
```

Comment: Никаким. *(7 символов нужно...)*

Answer (score 1):

Никак! `<input type="file">` только для чтения и вставить в него ничего нельзя.

Comment: Документация [<input type="file">](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/file).